# Forcing website to 'reload' to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site which relies heavily on where the user is on the page. I have features that happen when certain distances are reached.

I want the user to be taken to the top of the page when/if they reload the page. Currently, they reload to where they left off. However that screws up the code that depends on page position.

Comment: `window.onload = function() { window.scrollTo(0, 0);}`

Comment: just in the header? never made a site that needed this before

Comment: Yes it should work once you put it in a `<script>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if plain vanilla javascript is what you need try [scrollTo(x, y)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

```
window.onLoad(window.scrollTo(x, y));
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution, like

```
location.href = "#"
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like below should work :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("html,body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 50); 
});
```

We don't exactly know when the browser jumps to the last-scroll position. This is why some form of delay after the page has loaded is necessary. Or you could scroll to top before the page reloads.

Comment: He didn't said he was using jQuery.

Comment: @Mr.bug  - One of the tags is jQuery so I believed that it would be suitable.

Comment: I have no preference since I use both in my site, just looking for the easiest solution which I believe was provided